# Which is correct to use one bottle vs a bottle

Tags: phrase-usage

1. I can see **a bottle** of coke in the picture.
2. I can see **one bottle** of coke in the picture.

Can they be used interchangeably or do they have different meanings?
Is the function of one a kind of emphasis? or anything else
Would you pls explain to me the exact meaning of the above quantifiers?

Comment: They reflect the same state of things but the emphasis is different. 1) focuses on there being coke in the picture, 2) focuses on the number/quantity

Comment: **A/an** (noun) = an example of a (noun); **One** (noun) gives the number of nouns and emphasises that number.

Answer (score 1):

It's often said that the indefinite article "a" and the number one are interchangeable, but we use articles and numbers in different ways to emphasise different things.

In the simple context of your example, saying you see "one" bottle would emphasise the fact that there is only one on its own. It could be interpreted that there could have been more bottles there - that you expected more, or perhaps were told to look for more. Saying "a bottle" does not carry that implication - it's just what you see.

But in other contexts, we might use "one" to emphasise *uniqueness* in the same way that we might use the *definite* article 'the'. For example, someone might say "*there is only one Elvis Presley*", which does not mean that there has only ever been one person named that, but rather that the one everybody has heard of was unique or special. Likewise, you can use the definite article to distinguish a well-known person from others that may share their name, such as saying "*the* Elvis Presley".

Comment: Great explanation, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The word "one" is a number and (probably) works in a very similar way to the number word in your language.  (Nearly) all languages have words for numbers.

The word "a" is a functional word.  It is part of the grammar of English.  English has a grammatical system of articles, and a grammatical system of singular and plural countable nouns.  A singular countable noun which is not determined by any other determiner requires the indefinite article "a".  If you happen to speak a language that does not use articles, or does not distinguish between singular and plural, you would not mark the meaning of "a" in any way.

---

I'll illustrate this with Japanese, a language with neither plural nor articles. A natural translation into Japanese has no word meaning "a".  The Japanese sentence is ambiguous in English.  It could mean one, two or more bottles.  Japanese also doesn't need a subject, so "I" is implied by context

```
Tēburu no ue ni kōkusu no botoru ga miemasu

Table  's  on   Coke  's  bottle () can see

I can see a bottle of coke on the table.
```

But Japanese does have a word meaning "one"

```
Tēburu no ue ni kōkusu no botoru ga hitotsu miemasu

Table  's  on   Coke  's  bottle ()  one    can see

I can see one bottle of coke on the table.
```

The English doesn't have verb endings to indicate politeness, so the English is also ambiguous in Japanese.